# ToLowerCase if statement not working?

Tags: javascript, html

Ok so i got all of this to work other then my toLowerCase. it does not work so it will not split if it is case sensitive. I am using a drop down box to select my delimiter.

js code has been posted to help you guys point out the issue. i double checked it but i think it needs a new pair of eyes.

```
window.onload = function()  { 
document.getElementById("change").onclick = function () {
var paragraph = document.getElementById('box').value;
var x = document.getElementById("changeCase");
var getInfo = document.getElementById('ParaWrite');
var LowerCase = " ";
var LowerCase2 = " ";
var splitAT = " ";
var options = document.getElementById("split").value;
alert("above the for loop");

if (x.checked === true)
{
    LowerCase = paragraph.toLowerCase();
} 
else 
{
    LowerCase = paragraph;
}

for (var i = 0; i < document.form1.split.options.length; i++)
{
    if (document.form1.split.options[i].selected === true)
    {
        splitAT = paragraph.split(options);
        alert("splitAT[" + i + "]=" + splitAT[i]);

    }
}
console.log(document.form1.split.options);
document.write(splitAT +" " +splitAT.length);
}
```

HTML code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>Paragraph</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Textbox.css">

</head>

<body>
<h1>Please enter some Text</h1>
<form name="form1" id="form1">

<textarea type="text" id="box" value=""/></textarea>
<label for="write">Case Sensitive checkbox</label>
<input type='checkbox' name='write' id='changeCase' value='Check'/><br>

<input  type='button' value="Count" id="change"/>
<select name="split" id="split">
        <option value="like">like</option>
        <option value="monkey">monkey</option>
        <option value="I">I</option>
        <option value=".">.</option>
        <option value=",">,</option>
        <option value="?">?</option>
        <option value=" ">[Space]</option>
    </select>    
</form>
<div id="ParaWrite">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="die.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @MadProgrammer: a bit slow tonight, aren't we? :p

Comment: No guys, it's Java !== Javascript.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Firewall not allowing AJAX call backs makes getting updates an really pain :(

Comment: well i put java.. because toLowerCase is the same in both.... lol sorry guys did not want to make anyone mad ;)

Comment: @user2041757: no it's not the same in both, and even if it were, your question does not involve Java in any way shape or form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some comments:

```
> <!doctype html>
```

The string ["doctype"](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html) **must** be capitals to have the desired effect:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

> <form name="form1" id="form1">
```

If the form has an ID, it doesn't need a name. You can access the form using the `forms` collection (as you have in one place):

```
var theForm = document.forms.form1;
```

and then access all the form controls as named properties of the form.

```
> <textarea type="text" id="box" value=""/></textarea>
```

Textarea elements don't have a type or value attribute, their value is their content. You can't use SHORTAG syntax for an element that **must** have a closing tag, and don't use them for elements with not content if the DOCTYPE is HTML. Also, form controls must have a name to be successful. If they have a name and are in a form, they don't need an ID:

```
<textarea type="text" name="box" value=""></textarea>
```

Where you have:

```
> <input type='checkbox' name='write' id='changeCase' value='Check'>
```

it is not a good idea to have a form control with a different values for the name and id attributes. Better to just use a name (and don't use XML syntax in an HTML document):

```
<input type='checkbox' name='write' value='Check'>
```

Also:

```
> document.write(splitAT +" " +splitAT.length);
```

That will erase the entire document (including all head and script content) and replace it with the argument to document.write. Do you really want to do that?

There are many other issues with your code, perhaps you should just say what you want it to do, then you might get more help.

#### Edit

Working code:

```
<script>
  window.onload = function()  { 
    var form = document.forms.form1;

    form.change.onclick = function () {
      var paragraph = form.box.value;
      var getInfo = document.getElementById('ParaWrite');
      var splitAt = form.split.value;

      if (form.write.checked) {
         paragraph = paragraph.toLowerCase();
      }

      getInfo.innerHTML = paragraph.split(splitAt) + '<br>' +
                          paragraph.split(splitAt).length;
    }
  }
</script>

<form name="form1">
  <textarea name="box"></textarea>
  <label for="write">Make lower case</label>
  <input type='checkbox' name='write' id="write" value='Check'><br>
  <input  type='button' value="Count" name="change">
  <select name="split">
        <option value="like">like</option>
        <option value="monkey">monkey</option>
        <option value="I">I</option>
        <option value=".">.</option>
        <option value=",">,</option>
        <option value="?">?</option>
        <option value=" ">[Space]</option>
  </select>    
</form>
<div id="ParaWrite"></div>
```

Comment: Re "The string "doctype" must be capitals to have the desired effect", that is true for XML, but [the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#doctype-syntax) says "A normal doctype consists of the following parts, in exactly the following order:
1. Any **case-insensitive** match for the string `"<!DOCTYPE"`..."

Comment: In practice it probably doesn't matter, after all, HTML5 documents both existing and new behaviour (mostly without distinguishing which is which) so likely it's not case sensitive to be tolerant. But it's certainly convention to use upper case for DOCTYPE.

Comment: I agree re the importance of knowing the convention.  I hope my language-lawyerese isn't annoying -- when parsers and content generators agree about the meanings of strings, distributed apps are better off, so I try to spread around knowledge of what must seem to be spec trivia.

Comment: No problem, especially when appropriate references to specifications are provided. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would try

```
If (x.checked)
```

Avoiding === true, in case it is not a pure Boolean

Or check the value

Comment: The checked property is [defined](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-input-element.html#attr-input-checked) as being boolean, what other type might its value be?

Comment: I got it fixed... i called and set a tolowercase but never got it so i put the the for loop within the If statement.

Comment: There is no need for a for loop, just get the value of the select.